# How do I convert an integer class to a month class in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column named month in my dataframe called Trips which has a numerical format i.e. 1,..,12. The class for the months column is integer. I want to convert this column class into a Date(month) format so that I am able to later use scale_x_date in a ggplot function to display Months as labels instead of 2.5 and so on.

Comment: A number between 1 and 12 cannot be a date, which means you cannot use `scale_x_date`, period. If you know the year and day of month, *then* you can have a date. Lacking something reproducible, I'm going to guess that you can use something like `month <- factor(month, levels=format(1:12, "%b"))` (untested) and, if you need to change the x axis, then use `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: Yes, I got round it without defining the class for month and simply using scale_x_discrete(limits = month.abb) in my ggplot

Answer (score 0):

I gave you two options, one is in base R and the second with the `lubridate`package.

```
library(lubridate)
Trips <- tibble(month = c(1,3,12,3,6,2,3,7))
Trips$month2 <- month.abb[Trips$month]
Trips$L_month <- month(Trips$month, label = FALSE)
Trips$L_month_labels <- month(Trips$month, label = TRUE)
```

Comment: This does not help me create a ggplot graph later as using scale_x_date requires the class for month to be 'date'.